# How to solve this equation with sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, equation

Recently I got a long equation to solve that looks like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmp8P.png).

I've tried to solve this using `sympy.solveset()`, but it returned ConditionSet which means it couldn't handle this equation. How can I solve this equation using simpy library and if not at least in python? The code that I used:

```
import sympy as sp

t = sp.symbols('t')
a = 1.46
b = 1.2042 * 10**-4 * ((1.2275 * 10**-5 + t) * sp.ln(1.2275 * 10**-5 + t) - t)

result = sp.solveset(sp.Eq(a, b), t)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a transcendental equation. It possibly has an analytic solution in terms of the Lambert W function but I'm not sure. I'll assume that you just want a numerical solution which you can get using `nsolve`:

```
In [42]: nsolve(a - b, t, 1)                                                                                                                   
Out[42]: 1857.54700584719
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Can I be 100% sure this answer is correct? It's pretty important.

Comment: And also what this 1 means as an argument?

Comment: The `1` is the initial guess. You can plot the function to see what roots it has if you are unsure.